# PS3 controller on Sixad disbales Broadcom Bluetooth

Tags: wireless, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, ps3

The recipe for breaking blue tooth is so far:

Fresh install - blue tooth is happy
install broadcom drivers for wifi
Update to latest ubu
install sixad
run it once through and check ps3 controller is working.
reboot
Bluetooth is dead

or if I disable blue-tooth before reboot it won't come back either.

Latest stable Ubuntu - inbuilt bluetooth module. Hp Probook 6470b.

UPDATE

Running sixad via:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sixad
```

Then:

```
sudo sixpair
sixad --start
```

And turning off bluetooth to disconnect the PS3 controller and ctrl c the terminal means bluetooth can't be reactivated. Even after a reboot.

Help is appreciated! I'm very new to Ubuntu so be gentle.

UPDATE 2

Reinstalling **bluez,**  fixes it...

Answer (score 2):

sixad -r 
will restore regular bluetooth.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you setup sixad to startup automatically. You can switch it back over to using sixad as the bluetooth service with 'sixad -s'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that permission of `/usr/sbin/bluetoothd` has changed, so you can do:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
sudo service bluetoothd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that I had the option sixad --boot-yes enabled. After disabling (--boot-no), rebooting and manually starting sixad it worked fine again.